# Change multiple file names in sub directories in single line

Tags: bash, rename

I have a directory named backup. Backup contains several subdirectories named monday, tuesday, wednesday... each subfolder contains file named filename.txt
I want to change all names filename.txt to someothername.txt.
How can I do that in one line in bash?

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in backup/*/filename.txt; do mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/someothername.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is if you want to keep the basename and just change the extension in a bunch of files located in some subdirectories:

```
for f in ./*/*.yaml;
   do mv ${f} "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename ${f%.*}).yml";
done
```

or

```
for f in ./*/*.yaml;
   do mv ${f} "${f%.*}.yml";
done
```